# Having to switch compiler compliance levels every time I add a requestmapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, java-8, java-11

I am using java 11, Tomcat 9, and Spring 5 on windows 10.

I've run into a strange issue.  I am working on a spring-mvc app.  Every time I add or alter a RequestMapping I get a 404 no handler found error.  But when I switch the compiler compliance level for the project to 1.8 the error goes away.  Then I add a new RequestMapping and the 404 error pops back up.  So I switch compiler compliance level back to 11 and the error goes away.  And so on and so forth - every time I add a request mapping I am having to change my compiler compliance level.

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the project instead of changing the compiler compliance level?

Comment: Yes, my first thought when this happened was that since eclipse rebuilds the project after a compliance level change that it was the rebuilding that fixed my problem.  However when I try right clicking on my project and selecting build -- that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Rightclick -> Build does not **re**build afaik. Do `Project` -> `Clean ...` -> `Clean all` -> `[Clean]`.

Comment: Just a couple of tips: are you sure you are using only spring 5 and no other spring jar is in oyur classpath? are you using maven? may you post the pom.xml and the dependency tree? did yoy try to build the artifact outside eclipse and deploy it in tomcat9? are you sure you are using everywhere jdk11?

Comment: Thanks Selaron and Angelo... cleaning the project worked and the problem disappeared.

Comment: But why do I need to do this?

Comment: I recommend IntelliJ, just open your project in IntelliJ u wont have such problems))